# How do i let the user upload and use a picture

Tags: javascript, image, upload, onclick

Hey i'm using PhoneGap to make an App where the user can click on an img and then select an img from there phone to use instead, it's important for the lay out that it's only the picture you can see and click on.

Is it possible to make this in javascript/html? Please help me im 100% lost.

Comment: Welcome to SO please take a tour of the [help centre](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to see [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and what types of question are [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for this site.

Comment: I will do that the next time i have a free hour. But can you ask(help) me with my problem?

Comment: No as it is off topic

Comment: Is it the thing bout PhoneGap? Because that dosn't really do anything to the script. What i need is really just a way to let the user click on an img and upload hes/hers own instead of the old one

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to upload files using HTML to a web server. You will also need PHP to process and move the uploaded file to the desired destination. Many validation checks should be done on the uploaded image file to prevent any vulnerability. For this PHP is required. Without proper validation, it is a security risk for your app/server.

Eg:

**HTML Code(index.html):**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select image to upload:
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

**PHP Code (upload.php):**

```
<?php
    $target_dir = "uploads/";
    $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
    $uploadOk = 1;
    $imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    // Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
    if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
        $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
            echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
            $uploadOk = 1;
        } else {
            echo "File is not an image.";
            $uploadOk = 0;
        }
    }
?>
```

To know more about uploading and processing files,
[W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp)

Hope this helped you. Feel free to ask for any assistance.

Comment: When i have picked my img and click upload the website - the img wasn't found or might have been deleted. Even though i haven't thouch it. It dos so with all my img's.
Also do you know a way where there dosn't apperas buttons on the screen and it's just a img you click on to upload the new imgs in it's place.